# Using sessionStorage to keep values in select values when leaving the page Angular

Tags: angular, session-storage, select-options

Well, the title almost says it all,

I'm using sessionStorage of angular to store some values selected in a form and show them again as selected values when the user gets back to that form, The issue that I'm facing is that I can store the values and recuperate them but I can't get them selected in my select inputs

I've tried to use [selected]  but it still doesn't show up ! please help

Thank you

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to know with wich type of data are you handling in the select and how to correctly map that data, i understand your problem because it's normal at the beginning to have them so here some tips from me, that show how to handle this situation, all code are commented, if you don't understand something feel free to ask for more information.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfncmm

HTML:

```
<p>Select with only string</p>


<select  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
<!--  You cant bind in value an object you need to bind string ids-->
  <option [value]="x.name" *ngFor="let x of selectData">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>

<p>You just selected to be</p><strong>{{selectedValue}}</strong>


<p>Save data in localstorage</p>
<button type="button" (click)="saveData()">SAVE IT</button>
<button type="button" (click)="fetchData()">FETCH IT</button>

<hr>

<p>Select with object data</p>


<select  [(ngModel)]="selectedObject">
  <!--  You can bind object with ngValue-->
  <option [ngValue]="x" *ngFor="let x of selectData">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>

<p>You just selected to be</p> <strong>{{selectedObject?.id}} - {{selectedObject?.name}}</strong>


<p>Save data in localstorage</p>
<button type="button" (click)="saveDataObject()">SAVE IT</button>
<button type="button" (click)="fetchDataObject()">FETCH IT</button>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// tslint:disable-next-line:class-name
interface DataI {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const data: DataI[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Markus'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Anna'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Jhon'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Lori'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectData: DataI[];
  selectedValue: string;
  selectedObject: DataI;

  constructor() {
    this.selectData = data;
  }


  // In case you want to store object, the local and session storage don't accept objects, so you need to stringify them
  saveDataObject() {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedObj', JSON.stringify(this.selectedObject));
    // Refresh the page only for the example of rivisiting the app
    location.reload();
  }

  // When you fetch them just parse the string in json
  fetchDataObject() {
    this.selectedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedObj'));
    this.mapSelectedData();
  }

  /* When you fetch the object the data will not be displayed on the select because in javascript you can't
  assume that a obj equal to another obj only because they share same data so you need the original reference used
   */

  mapSelectedData() {
    this.selectedObject = this.selectData
      .filter(x => x.id === this.selectedObject.id)
      .map(x => x)
      .reduce(x => x);
  }


  saveData() {
    localStorage.setItem('selected', this.selectedValue);
    // Refresh the page only for the example of rivisiting the app
    location.reload();
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.selectedValue = localStorage.getItem('selected');
  }
}
```

I stored everything in localstorage, bacause session storage once you leave the domain, the session expire and delete all data if you want to save it persistently you need to store in localstorage, if you want to save only for the session, using sessionStorage is good with some redux pattern, but for saving some data just use a service that store all the data in memory.

Comment: SO, when i want to store my values in localStorage i create a new object nd store in its properties the values from localstorage then when the obj.name equals obj2.name i set a boolean vraiable to true and then in my html [selected]="booleanVariable" so i don't see what i'am doing wrong here

Comment: I created a stackblitz maybe can help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfncmm